# Not able to copy the clipboard data using javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, clipboarddata

One of the clients have the set the "Disabled" for the setting - "Allow Programmatinc clipboard access". 
And hence, the below line of code which is for copying a text into clipboard is not working - 
    window.clipboardData.setData('Text', 'copied programmatically');

is there any workaround for this client without changing his IE settings/preferencess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Request the client to add our site(application developer/owner) to the trusted sites or a different zone.
2) And set the setting - "Allow Programmatinc clipboard access" specific to this site using the Registry Entry:

- Go to Registry entry.
- Add the application site to a different zone - lest us say "6"
- And set the setting "Allow Programmatinc clipboard access" equvalent dw-word is 1407 for this zone.